# Can we open existing web application using AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to AWS Lambda. I am able to create a Web application and manage it using AWS Lambda function but is it possible to open existing web application and manage them?

For instance, I want to open a Gmail application in a browser and enter the details in a sign up page via AWS Lambda automatically. Can some one please confirm if this is possible and if yes kindly guide me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the web application has an end-point then with `POST` method you could pass data from a lambda function.

Getting started with AWS Lambda - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-create-function.html

Some pointers -

1. Lambda function needs to reside in a private subnet under a VPC.
2. Reason being, a lambda function doesn't have a public IP address to traverse through the internet.

Try with a proof of concept, before hitting an actual application. Works for me!

Let me if that helps!